# Vaadin-date-picker dynamically set a default date using Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, polymer, vaadin-elements, vaadin-date-picker

I'm trying to set a default date dynamically in vaadin-date-picker using Angular2. While implementing these task on my project it shows an exception.

PFA of My code and Error

Thank you.

Click for exception image: [Exception Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvJQM.png)
Click for code Image[Code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRH2X.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer is here : https://vaadin.com/forum#!/thread/13790736

Thanks

```
    pad(i: number) {
  return i < 10 ? '0' + i : i;
}

ngOnInit() {
  const selectedDate = new Date();
  this.birthday = `${selectedDate.getFullYear()}-${this.pad(selectedDate.getMonth() + 1)}-${this.pad(selectedDate.getDate())}`;
}
```